# Xcode 5 crashes on loading 4.6 projects

Tags: xcode5

after installing Xcode 5 I am unable to load any pre-existing projects. any project created in Xcode 5 opens fine, but anything created before hand causes the application to crash on load with the following crash report:

```
Interval Since Last Report:          3191 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           17
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  839 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   12
Anonymous UUID:                      788D37B9-342D-C906-4E63-675844504D81

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: IDEContainer - uniquing lock

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-   3564.1/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/MacroExpansion/XCMacroExpansionE xtensions.mm:92
Details:  Assertion failed: [value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
Object:   <DVTMacroDefinitionTable: 0x7fe5f6ade810>
Method:   -_xc_setValue:forMacroName:conditionSet:errorHandler:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe5f2c14b80>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
0  0x000000010ee69188 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
```

I have deleted all derived data folders and disabled the built in source control, but nothing seems to have an affect. Anyone know how to remedy this issue?